Why a difference in Score for Manhattan distance vs Cosine Distance despite same text chunk being returned?
I am using the qdrant DB and client for embedding a document as part of a PoC that I am working on in building a RAG.
I see that when I use a Manhattan distance to build the vector collection I get a high score than when I use the Cosine distance. However, the text chunk returned is the same. I am not able to understand why and how? I am learning my ropes here at RAG still. Thanks in advance.
USER QUERY
What is DoS?

COSINE DISTANCE
response: [
ScoredPoint(id=0, 
version=10, 
score=0.17464592, 
payload={
'chunk': "It also includes overhead bytes for operations, 
administration, and maintenance (OAM) purposes.\nOptical Network Unit 
(ONU)\nONU is a device used in Passive Optical Networks (PONs). It converts 
optical signals transmitted via fiber optic cables into electrical signals that 
can be used by end-user devices, such as computers and telephones. The ONU is 
located at the end user's premises and serves as the interface between the optical 
network and the user's local network."
}, 
vector=None, shard_key=None)
]

MANHATTAN DISTANCE
response: [
ScoredPoint(id=0, 
version=10, 
score=103.86209, 
payload={
'chunk': "It also includes overhead bytes for operations, administration, 
and maintenance (OAM) purposes.\nOptical Network Unit 
(ONU)\nONU is a device used in Passive Optical Networks (PONs). It converts 
optical signals transmitted via fiber optic cables into electrical signals that 
can be used by end-user devices, such as computers and telephones. The ONU is 
located at the end user's premises and serves as the interface between the optical 
network and the user's local network."
}, 
vector=None, shard_key=None)
]


There are many different math functions that can be used to calculate similarity between two embedding vectors:

Cosine distance,
Manhattan distance (L1 norm),
Euclidean distance (L2 norm),
Dot product,
etc.

Each calculates similarity in a different way, where:

The Cosine distance measures the cosine of the angle between two non-zero vectors. The Cosine distance is sensitive to the direction of the vectors and is less sensitive to the magnitude.



The Manhattan distance measures the absolute difference between the corresponding elements of two vectors. The Manhattan distance is sensitive to the magnitude of the vectors.



The Euclidean distance measures the straight-line distance between two vectors.



The Dot product measures the angle between two vectors multiplied by the product of their magnitudes.


Note: Image source for all four images
Consequently, the results of similarity calculations are different, where:

The Cosine distance is always in the range [0, 2].
The Manhattan distance is always in the range [0, ∞).
The Euclidean distance is always in the range [0, ∞).
The Dot product is always in the range (-∞, ∞).

See the table below.



Measure
Range
Interpretation




Cosine distance
[0, 2]
0 if vectors are the same, 2 if they are diametrically opposite.


Manhattan distance
[0, ∞)
0 if vectors are the same, increases with the sum of absolute differences.


Euclidean distance
[0, ∞)
0 if vectors are the same, increases with the sum of squared differences.


Dot product
(-∞, ∞)
Measures alignment, can be positive, negative, or zero based on vector direction.



